# RESTKIT request mapping for unknown keys

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

```
{
    "type": "at or leave",
    "time": "XXXX",
    "place_name": "Xx",
    "place_id": "xx",
    "place_attributes": {
        "key": "val",
        "key2": "val2",
    },
    "place_type": "public or private"
}
```

i want to post json like above.But placeAttributes dictionary in my app will be having unknown number of keys which are needed to be mapped with "place_attributes" in json above.

Comment: What did you try? What did it do? Did you try `RKDynamicMapping`?

Comment: no , had thought of creating place attribute class and using relationship mapping. but i am not sure of the keys present in dictionary so cannot create custom class.

Comment: Try the dynamic mapping and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Rkdynamicmapping mapping for request mapping?

Comment: what if i create nsdictionary property and map my dictionary to this property?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47500/discussion-between-satyam-raikar-and-wain)

Answer (score 0):

Created a NSDictionary* placeAttributes property in my request mapping class, mapped it  to place_attributes key in json and directly assigned my dictionary to placeAttributes.

```
RKObjectMapping* map = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                          @"type":@"type",
                                          @"time":@"time",
                                          @"place_name":@"place_name",
                                          @"place_id":@"place_id",
                                          @"place_type":@"place_type",
                                          @"placeAttributes":@"place_attributes"
                                          }];
```